# Recursive class in python and a bug in thrift

Tags: python, c, recursion, thrift

Thrift 0.9.2 now allows for recursive structs that can contain instances of themselves.  For example this thrift definition:

```
namespace py foo

struct Foo {
    1: optional string member
    2: optional Foo fooData
}
```

Produces the following code:

```
#
# Autogenerated by Thrift Compiler (0.9.2)
#
# DO NOT EDIT UNLESS YOU ARE SURE THAT YOU KNOW WHAT YOU ARE DOING
#
#  options string: py
#

from thrift.Thrift import TType, TMessageType, TException, TApplicationException

from thrift.transport import TTransport
from thrift.protocol import TBinaryProtocol, TProtocol
try:
  from thrift.protocol import fastbinary
except:
  fastbinary = None



class Foo:
  """
  Attributes:
   - member
   - fooData
  """

  thrift_spec = (
    None, # 0
    (1, TType.STRING, 'member', None, None, ), # 1
    (2, TType.STRUCT, 'fooData', (Foo, Foo.thrift_spec), None, ), # 2
  )

  def __init__(self, member=None, fooData=None,):
    self.member = member
    self.fooData = fooData

  def read(self, iprot):
    if iprot.__class__ == TBinaryProtocol.TBinaryProtocolAccelerated and isinstance(iprot.trans, TTransport.CReadableTransport) and self.thrift_spec is not None and fastbinary is not None:
      fastbinary.decode_binary(self, iprot.trans, (self.__class__, self.thrift_spec))
      return
    iprot.readStructBegin()
    while True:
      (fname, ftype, fid) = iprot.readFieldBegin()
      if ftype == TType.STOP:
        break
      if fid == 1:
        if ftype == TType.STRING:
          self.member = iprot.readString();
        else:
          iprot.skip(ftype)
      elif fid == 2:
        if ftype == TType.STRUCT:
          self.fooData = Foo()
          self.fooData.read(iprot)
        else:
          iprot.skip(ftype)
      else:
        iprot.skip(ftype)
      iprot.readFieldEnd()
    iprot.readStructEnd()

  def write(self, oprot):
    if oprot.__class__ == TBinaryProtocol.TBinaryProtocolAccelerated and self.thrift_spec is not None and fastbinary is not None:
      oprot.trans.write(fastbinary.encode_binary(self, (self.__class__, self.thrift_spec)))
      return
    oprot.writeStructBegin('Foo')
    if self.member is not None:
      oprot.writeFieldBegin('member', TType.STRING, 1)
      oprot.writeString(self.member)
      oprot.writeFieldEnd()
    if self.fooData is not None:
      oprot.writeFieldBegin('fooData', TType.STRUCT, 2)
      self.fooData.write(oprot)
      oprot.writeFieldEnd()
    oprot.writeFieldStop()
    oprot.writeStructEnd()

  def validate(self):
    return


  def __hash__(self):
    value = 17
    value = (value * 31) ^ hash(self.member)
    value = (value * 31) ^ hash(self.fooData)
    return value

  def __repr__(self):
    L = ['%s=%r' % (key, value)
      for key, value in self.__dict__.iteritems()]
    return '%s(%s)' % (self.__class__.__name__, ', '.join(L))

  def __eq__(self, other):
    return isinstance(other, self.__class__) and self.__dict__ == other.__dict__

  def __ne__(self, other):
    return not (self == other)
```

The problem with this code is in the class variable `thrift_spec`:

```
thrift_spec = (
    None, # 0
    (1, TType.STRING, 'member', None, None, ), # 1
    (2, TType.STRUCT, 'fooData', (Foo, Foo.thrift_spec), None, ), # 2
  )
```

There are two problems here:

1. The class def tries to reference `Foo` before it is fully defined (and will produce `NameError: name 'Foo' is not defined`) when instantiated.
2. `thrift_spec` tries to contain a reference to itself which is a bizarre thing to do in python (self-referential tuple?).

This tuple is used by a package in thrift called fastbinary, a C-module that serializes and deserializes thrift objects natively. The tuple is used to pass along type information to the C-module.

The question I have is how best to solve these two problems. For #1 I can move the instantiation of thrift_spec after the class definition or could move it into an @property. For #2 I'm really not sure what to do. Is there some way to get a reference to the tuple object and pass that to the C-module?

Note this is an open bug in thrift that I was hoping to help solve:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/THRIFT-2642

Comment: There's no way to build a tuple like that through standard Python-level APIs, and even if you do it by messing with the C api directly, it'll break things, since Python assumes tuples can't look like that. Would it be possible to use something other than a tuple for the `thrift_spec`?

Comment: Yea, I think that's the way to go.  I'll probably just try using some sentinel value that I look for in the C-module that means get a reference to myself.